# Artifactory bad gateway error

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use artifactory as a docker registry. But pushing docker images gives a Bad Gateway error.

Following is my nginx configuration

```
upstream artifactory_lb {
        server artifactory01.mycomapany.com:8081;
        server artifactory01.mycomapany.com:8081 backup;
        server myLoadBalancer.mycompany.com:8081;
}

log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443  ssl;
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        location /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow all;
                }
}

# Server configuration

server {
    listen 2222 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/self-signed/self.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/self-signed/self.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    server_name myloadbalancer.mycompany.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/docker_repo/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    location / {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
    proxy_pass http://myloadbalancer.company.com:8081/artifactory/;

    }

}
```

The docker command I use to push images is

```
docker push myloadbalancer:2222/image_name
```

Nginx error logs show the following error 24084 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: internal_ip, server: , request: "GET /artifactory/inhouse HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http:/internal_ip:8081/artifactory/repo"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by changing the proxy pass to point to any of the upstream servers.

```
proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
```